# How to update only one row in DataView from SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, dataview

I have a situation where I have a grid loaded with data. It is not data
bound. Clicking an image opens up another form that allows the change of
the data in the grid.

Right now the changed data (1 row) is written to the DB and the whole
grid is reloaded from the DB which now incorporates the change.

My question is can I update the data in a data view? That way I can
right the change to the DB and update the DataView without having to dip
the DB every time and essentially avoid reloading a 1000 rows of data
because I changed one.

How do I change one row in a DataView?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a generally supported feature, because it would only work if you were doing a straight select * from table query, with a known PK. Any time you had any joins, or aggregate functions involved etc, the entire query would need to be executed in order to get the value of that row.

Why aren't you using databinding? If your grid is bound to a datatable, and you do your update that way, then the grid would be automatically updated by virtue of being bound to the table.

Even if you do not want to do full round-trip databinding, if you still use the table, just update the table with the appropriate changes, and then re-bind the grid.